# Scipy ODR results with huge relative errors for sd_beta

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting, one-definition-rule

When running the ODR algorithm on some experiment data, I've been asked to run it with the following model:

[image: fitting function 1]

It is clear that this fitting function is containing a redundant degree of freedom.

When I run the fitting on my experiment data I get enormous relative errors of beta, starting from 8000% relative error.

When I try to run the fitting again but with a fitting function that doesn't have a redundant degree of freedom, such as:

[image: hyperbolic fitting]

I don't get this kind of problem.

Why is this happening? Why the ODR algorithm is so sensitive for redundant degrees of freedom? I wasn't able to answer these questions to my supervisors. An answer will be much appreciated.

Reproducing code example:

```py
from scipy.odr import RealData, Model, ODR


def func1(a, x):
    return a[0] * (x + a[1]) / (a[3] * (x + a[1]) + a[1] * x) + a[2]


def func2(a, x):
    return a[0] / (x + a[1]) + a[2]


# fmt: off
zx = [
    1911.125, 2216.95, 2707.71, 3010.225, 3410.612, 3906.015, 4575.105, 5517.548,
    6918.481,
]
dx = [
    0.291112577, 0.321695254, 0.370771197, 0.401026507, 0.441068641, 0.490601621,
    0.557573268, 0.651755155, 0.79184836,
]
zy = [
    0.000998056, 0.000905647, 0.000800098, 0.000751041, 0.000699982, 0.000650532,
    0.000600444, 0.000550005, 0.000500201,
]
dy = [
    5.49029e-07, 5.02824e-07, 4.5005e-07, 4.25532e-07, 3.99991e-07, 3.75266e-07,
    3.50222e-07, 3.25003e-07, 3.00101e-07,
]
# fmt: on

data = RealData(x=zx, y=zy, sx=dx, sy=dy)

print("Func 1")
print("======")
beta01 = [
    1.46,
    4775.4,
    0.01,
    1000,
]
model1 = Model(func1)
odr1 = ODR(data, model1, beta0=beta01)
result1 = odr1.run()
print("beta", result1.beta)
print("sd beta", result1.sd_beta)
print("relative", result1.sd_beta / result1.beta * 100)


print()
print()


print("Func 2")
print("======")
beta02 = [
    1,
    1,
    1,
]
model2 = Model(func2)
odr2 = ODR(data, model2, beta0=beta02)
result2 = odr2.run()
print("beta", result2.beta)
print("sd beta", result2.sd_beta)
print("relative", result2.sd_beta / result2.beta * 100)
```

This prints out:

```
Func 1
======
beta [ 1.30884537e+00 -2.82585952e+03  7.79755196e-04  9.47943376e+01]
sd beta [1.16144608e+02 3.73765816e+06 6.12613738e-01 4.20775596e+03]
relative [   8873.82193523 -132266.24068473   78564.88054498    4438.82627453]


Func 2
======
beta [1.40128121e+00 9.80844274e+01 3.00511669e-04]
sd beta [2.73990552e-03 3.22344713e+00 3.74538794e-07]
relative [0.1955286  3.28640051 0.12463369]
```

Scipy/Numpy/Python version information:

Versions are:

- **Scipy** - 1.4.1
- **Numpy** - 1.18.2
- **Python** - 3.7.2

Comment: I'd say that is not an issue with the `ODR` but with chi^2 fitting in general. With an additional degree of freedom you smear out the minimum. This gives you a smaller curvature in the Hesse matrix and consequently larger errors. The correlation should be humongous as well.

Comment: ...after reading the answer of norok2 I also have to say that "degree of freedom" is the wrong term. You are talking about an obsolete parameter. This is either directly a correlation of +-1 as in the given answer ring of dependencies or .... many ways to construct this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with the degrees of freedom.

The degrees of freedom is the difference between the number of data points and the number of fitting parameters.
The problem has the same number of degrees of freedom for the two formulae, as they have the same number of parameters.
It also looks like that you do not have free degrees of freedom, which is good news, it means that it can potentially be fitted.

However, you are right that first expression has some problem: the parameters you are trying to fit are not independent.

This is probably better understood with some simpler example.

Consider the following expression:

```
y = x + b + c
```

which you try to fit, given `n` data for `x` and `y` with `n >> 2`.

The question is: what are the optimal value for `b` and `c`? This cannot be answered. All you can say from `x` and `y` data is about the combination. Therefore, if `b + c` is `0`, the fit cannot tell us if `b = 1000, c = -1000` or `b = 1, c= -1`, but at least we can say that given `b` we can determine `c`.
What is the error on a *given* `b`? Potentially infinite. That is the reason for the fitting to give you that large relative error.